# Pine script: strange behaviour within for loop

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am trying to optimise an SMA period within a for loop such that there is at least one cross between the `low` series and the SMA and the `high` series and a multiplier of the SMA. To do this, I use a for loop over candidate period values and for each candidate period value, I check whether the crosses mentioned earlier exist.

I notice some very strange behaviour which leads to garbage results.

Here's a sample code. Please try it on the **daily BITSTAMP:BTCUSD chart** so that the results you get are consistent with mine.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="test", shorttitle="test", overlay=true)

// functions
boolCross(series1, series2) =>
    not na(ta.valuewhen(ta.cross(series1, series2), series1, 0))

// initialize
debugText = ""

// demo
var int periodToUse = 0
for thisPeriod = 4999 to 1 by 200 
    periodToUse := thisPeriod
    boolUpperBandTouch = false
    boolLowerBandTouch = false
    sma = ta.sma(close, thisPeriod)
    if boolCross(high, sma * 5) 
        boolUpperBandTouch := true
    if boolCross(low, sma)
        boolLowerBandTouch := true
    if boolUpperBandTouch and boolLowerBandTouch
        break

debugText += "Value of periodToUse: " + str.tostring(periodToUse) + "\n"
debugText += "Is periodToUse == 4999? " + str.tostring(periodToUse == 4999) + "\n" 

plot(ta.sma(close, periodToUse), color = color.red, linewidth = 3)
plot(ta.sma(close, 4999), color = color.blue, linewidth = 3)

// display debug table
var debugTable = table.new(position = position.bottom_right, columns = 1, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
debugText += "End\n"
table.cell(debugTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = debugText, text_color = color.black, bgcolor = color.white)
```

As you can see, I have added a debug box to do some sanity checks. The for loop ends at the first iteration because apparently there are crosses for a period of 4999. I also check that the value returned == 4999. I then plot the SMA (red colour) band with `periodToUse` and I also plot another SMA (blue colour) band where I manually set the period to 4999. Obviously, I expect that the two SMAs should overlap. However, this is not the case.

[image]

As can be seen, the red SMA weirdly begins shortly after the first-ever candle (although, the period should be 4999), then has an abrupt move down and then it stops. As for the blue SMA, it never appears because a period of 4999 is too high (this is the correct and expected behaviour).

What am I doing wrong?

If I leave the for loop empty (i.e., exclude all the cross-checking logic), it works as expected:

//@

```
version=5
indicator(title="test", shorttitle="test", overlay=true)

// functions
boolCross(series1, series2) =>
    not na(ta.valuewhen(ta.cross(series1, series2), series1, 0))

// initialize
debugText = ""

// demo
var int periodToUse = 0
for thisPeriod = 4999 to 1 by 200 
    periodToUse := thisPeriod

debugText += "Value of periodToUse: " + str.tostring(periodToUse) + "\n"
debugText += "Is periodToUse == 199? " + str.tostring(periodToUse == 199) + "\n" 

plot(ta.sma(close, periodToUse), color = color.red, linewidth = 3)
plot(ta.sma(close, periodToUse) * 5, color = color.red, linewidth = 3)
plot(ta.sma(close, 199), color = color.blue, linewidth = 3)
plot(ta.sma(close, 199) * 5, color = color.blue, linewidth = 3)

// display debug table
var debugTable = table.new(position = position.bottom_right, columns = 1, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
debugText += "End\n"
table.cell(debugTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = debugText, text_color = color.black, bgcolor = color.white)
```

[image]

Only the blue band is visible because it overlaps the red one as expected.

---

Edit: in response to @John Baron's request for more information:

First do this on the **daily BITSTAMP:BTCUSD chart**:

```
plot(ta.sma(close, 1400), color = color.blue, linewidth = 3)
plot(ta.sma(close, 1400) * 5, color = color.blue, linewidth = 3)
```

You'll see this. This is our reference SMA:

[image]

Now replace that code with:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="test", shorttitle="test", overlay=true)

// functions
boolCross(series1, series2) =>
    ta.cum(ta.cross(series1, series2) ? 1 : 0) > 0

// initialize
debugText = ""

// main
var periodToUse = 0
for thisPeriod = 1400 to 1 by 200 
    periodToUse := thisPeriod
    sma = ta.sma(close, thisPeriod)
    boolUpperBandTouch = boolCross(high, sma * 5) 
    boolLowerBandTouch = boolCross(low, sma)
    if boolUpperBandTouch and boolLowerBandTouch
        break

debugText += "Value of periodToUse: " + str.tostring(periodToUse) + "\n"
debugText += "Is periodToUse == 1400? " + str.tostring(periodToUse == 1400) + "\n" 

plot(ta.sma(close, periodToUse), color = color.red, linewidth = 3) // <===== plots garbage
plot(ta.sma(close, periodToUse) * 5, color = color.red, linewidth = 3) // <===== plots garbage

// display debug table
var debugTable = table.new(position = position.bottom_right, columns = 1, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
table.cell(debugTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = debugText, text_color = color.black, bgcolor = color.white)
```

This is the output:
[image]

You'll see in the debug box on the bottom right corner that the value of `periodToUse` was 1400 (**the same value we used in the reference SMA above**. You will also see that the red SMA plot (which is plotted using `periodToUse (plot(ta.sma(close, periodToUse), color = color.red, linewidth = 3)`) looks completely different in comparison to the reference SMA (blue) which we plotted manually. Why is this? They should both be identical because we are *apparently* using the same period value.

Answer (score 0):

Just to simplify your script.

```
    for thisPeriod = 4999 to 1 by 200 
    periodToUse := thisPeriod
    sma = ta.sma(close, thisPeriod)
    boolUpperBandTouch = boolCross(high, sma * 5) 
    boolLowerBandTouch = boolCross(low, sma)
    if boolUpperBandTouch and boolLowerBandTouch
        break
```

This is not the challenge, the challenge is using valuewhen, which I think is giving you the irregular return. It seems you are not interested in the value but only interested in a touch.

Perhaps something like this might work better

```
    boolCross(series1, series2) =>
        ta.cum(ta.cross(series1,series2)?1:0)>0
```

Comment: I tried the simplified script (thanks) and the updated function. But I still get the same results. 

Perhaps I didn't explain myself earlier. I'll try again. If I use the `periodToUse` value that is returned from the `for` loop to plot an SMA, the plotted SMA is completely bogus (see the red curve with some sort of weird downward spike). If I manually plot an SMA with the same period that as `periodToUse`, I get the SMA that would be expected (see blue curve). So, again, to summarize: there appears to be a problem using `periodToUse` to plot an SMA.

Comment: Are you plotting periodToUse to see how and if it is changing?

Comment: Yes. I checked and periodToUse decrements by 200 as expected. However, the SMA that is calculated within the for loop is completely wrong.

Comment: do you mind posting your most current script in a way that I can run it and then describe what you mean by 'completely wrong'

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Life got in the way. This may be a multi-part response because of message size limitations. 

I can't add pictures, so you're going to have to do this at your end. 

Please do this on the daily BITSTAMP:BTCUSD chart. 

First do this:
    `plot(ta.sma(close, 1400), color = color.blue, linewidth = 3)
    plot(ta.sma(close, 1400) * 5, color = color.blue, linewidth = 3)`

This is how the SMA with period 1400 should look.

Comment: Now execute this script (sorry, can't format):

//@version=5

indicator(title="test", shorttitle="test", overlay=true)

// functions

boolCross(series1, series2) =>

    ta.cum(ta.cross(series1, series2) ? 1 : 0) > 0

// initialize

debugText = ""

// main
var periodToUse = 0
for thisPeriod = 1400 to 1 by 200 
    periodToUse := thisPeriod
    sma = ta.sma(close, thisPeriod)
    boolUpperBandTouch = boolCross(high, sma * 5) 
    boolLowerBandTouch = boolCross(low, sma)
    if boolUpperBandTouch and boolLowerBandTouch
        break

...continued...

Comment: ...continued...

debugText += "Value of periodToUse: " + str.tostring(periodToUse) + "\n"
debugText += "Is periodToUse == 1400? " + str.tostring(periodToUse == 1400) + "\n" 

plot(ta.sma(close, periodToUse), color = color.red, linewidth = 3) // <===== plots garbage
plot(ta.sma(close, periodToUse) * 5, color = color.red, linewidth = 3) // <===== plots garbage

...continued...

Comment: ...continued...

// display debug table
var debugTable = table.new(position = position.bottom_right, columns = 1, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
table.cell(debugTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = debugText, text_color = color.black, bgcolor = color.white)

// end of script

Comment: If it executed correctly, you'll see in the debug box on the bottom right corner that the value of `periodToUse` was 1400 (the same value we used in the reference SMA above. You will also see that the red SMA plot (which is plotted using `periodToUse` (`plot(ta.sma(close, periodToUse), color = color.red, linewidth = 3)`) looks completely different in comparison to the reference SMA (blue) which we plotted manually. Why is this? They should both be identical.

Comment: can u not edit your question to add the code into one block? i would like to try this more easily.

Comment: Done. Please see everything after the horizontal rule in the main question.

Comment: Anyone got a clue or is this going to remain an unsolved mystery?